# Subtrair um dia diretamente do CURRENT_DATE

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando um framework que me possibilita definir a data corrente como valor default, mas agora preciso mostrar para o usuário sempre a data de ontem, o trecho do código como o valor definido é esse:

```
$editor = new DateTimeEdit('datacadastro_edit', false, 'd-m-Y');
$editColumn = new CustomEditColumn('Data Cadastro', 'DataCadastro', $editor, $this->dataset);
$editColumn->SetReadOnly(true);
$editColumn->SetAllowSetToNull(true);
$editColumn->SetInsertDefaultValue($this->RenderText('%CURRENT_DATE%'));
$this->ApplyCommonColumnEditProperties($editColumn);
$grid->AddInsertColumn($editColumn);
```

O que tentei fazer foi isso:

```
$editColumn->SetInsertDefaultValue($this->RenderText('%CURRENT_DATE%'.' - 1 days'));
```

Mas a data exibida é a de hoje, não sei exatamente se esse é o meio mais correto para se fazer isso.

Comment: `DateTimeEdit` é um framework ou lib que esta usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em MYSQL todos esses dão certo :

```
SELECT
 CAST(current_date()-1 as date),
 Date(current_date()-1),
 DATE(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Isto não esta me parecendo uma classe nativa ou alguma lib fortemente conhecida, no entanto como usou a tag mysql se uma coluna em um `SELECT`:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Se for para retornar somente os resultados de "ontem":

```sql
SELECT colunas FROM tabela WHERE DATE(coluna_de_data) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

No `INSERT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO tabela (coluna1, coluna2, colunadedata)
VALUES ('valor1', 'valor2', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

No `UPDATE`:

```sql
UPDATE tabela
SET coluna1='valor1', column2='valor2', colunadedata=CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE <condição para edição(ões)>
```